# Repeating replicate() in R to change stepwise forward/back (change seed every time)

Tags: r, repeat, seed, replicate

Can not find the solution how to change "set.seed" by replicate(). I have to run the code  100 times for forward and backward stepwise in order to find inputs, which are relevant for differences between forward and backward step. Right now the model shows that both models are identical. However if we change the seed for both models (take the same for both), then I see that results could be different.

So right now I would like to run the code 100 times and get result for every time with different seed:

```
###########################################
model_forw <- function(seed){
    n <- 100
    p <- 20
    cv <- matrix(0.5,p,p)
    diag(cv) <- 1
    noise <- 5
    set.seed(seed)
    X <- mvrnorm(n,rep(0,p),cv)
    beta <- c(seq(from=1,to=2,length=p/2),rep(0,p/2))
    y <- X%*%beta+rnorm(n)*noise
    d <- data.frame(y=y,X=X)

    mod.full <- lm(y~.,data=d)
    mod.backward <- step(mod.full, trace=0)
    a <- summary(mod.backward)
    vars <- as.numeric(substr(dimnames(a$coefficients)[[1]][-1],3,4))
    vars
}

model_run <- function(N, seed){
     result <- replicate(n = N, model_forw(seed = seed))
     result 
}
```

so if I want to see just 1 model, then model_run(N = 1, seed = 123) works. And if I want to build 100 models with different seeds, I tried this one:

```
ss <- seq(0, 1, length=100) # various sample sizes
result <- sapply(ss, function(x)model_run(N = 1, seed = x))
result
```

Here I get some troubles with seeds, first it would be nice to get seeds for example from 123 to 12300 (100 of them). Secondly, my results are repeating the function 100 times for each seed, but I need 1 time for each seed and 100 different seeds. Any HINTS what should I change?

Comment: Not sure I totally understand your issue of repeating the function 100 times. But if you want a vector of length 100 from 123 to 12300 by 123: `ss <- seq(from = 123, to = 12300, by = 123)`

Comment: Is `mvrnorm` from MASS?

Comment: **mvrnorm** from MASS